# Adverbs of Manner

Tags: adverbs

Does it sound correct to say;
“A man was pointing **loudly** out to sea. Everyone looked to see what he was pointing at. There, only a few hundred yards out to sea, was the tell-tale triangular fin of a shark moving fast towards the beach.
Can the adverb **loudly** modify the phrase **point out**?
I mean, does it sound logical?

Comment: Definitely not! Only sounds can be loud.

Comment: You could say "A man was shouting loudly and pointing out to sea".

Comment: In this case, what an adverb of manner can be used here? In the “A WORKBOOK OF ENGLISH GRAMMAR” by Katherine Watson, there is given a fill in the gap short story, without providing any words to use, where I met this very sentence;      A man was pointing _____ out to sea. Everyone looked to see what he was pointing at.

Comment: @KateBunting Nonsense, you can have a loud shirt. "Loud" can also mean obviously, conspicuously.

Comment: @Astralbee Yes, a garish colour can be metaphorically 'loud', but a loud gesture??

Comment: @KateBunting I agree it would be unusual, but nothing in the dictionary definition - "in manner that attracts attention" - suggests it would be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

'Loudly' *can* mean "*ostentatiously; conspicuously; showily; glaringly*", but its primary meaning is related to sound. You could use it in your context, it might confuse a minority of people and cause some others to reach for the dictionary, but it is interesting use of language. Logically then, you *could* say "he loudly pointed out the shark", but if you don't want to have a debate with your English teacher you might be better going for a safer adverb.

More common choices might be:

- frantically
- furiously
- energetically

For example:

- He frantically pointed out to sea
- A man was pointing furiously out to sea